# How to monitor a Windows shares for changes?

Tags: windows, logging, directory, monitoring, network-share

I want to create a program which monitors and logs creation, modification, deletion of files in a directory, most importantly it should be able log the username/SID of the user who made those changes from which pc/host/IP address. I don't want to utilize Windows file auditing. I want to create a opensource alternative to Netwrix, ManageEngine file server auditor and other similar tools.

I have tried python watchdog library but it cannot log user details. I am currently trying C# Windows APIs. I would love for any help regarding this. I would prefer Python, C#, .NET but any other languages would work.